# Managing system-wide parameters in C

Tags: c, parameters

I'm developing a system of many processes which have to be aware of many configurations, options and data of the system. For doing that, I implement a shared object that use a pointer to a shared memory block of parameters and their data. The data of the parameters are the types, the values, default values, functions for get/set and etc. Basically the data is in a kind of look-up table.
This shared object has some functions for get/set these parameters, so all the processes in the system can get/set these many parameters. I have many defines for the parameters codes and many possibilities for each parameter, for example, one code can be a float value, and another is an array of ints. You can only imagine the complexity of the code with all the switch and cases..

My questions are:

Does this practice is correct for handling a system-wide parameters and configurations? for speed and efficiency I don't want to use a DB file, I have to keep the data close in the RAM. I thought about moving the look-up table in-memory DB but the processing time is critical and I don't want to waste time on building SQL statements and compiling them. Any ideas of what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program design sounds fine, given that he parameters are properly encapsulated in a separate file, declared as static and only accessible through set/get functions. Then the code for accessing the data, as well as any potential thread-safety code, can be placed in the same file and hidden from the caller.

Whenever it makes most sense to keep the parameters in RAM or in a DB really just depends on how fast you need the data available. It sounds like this isn't an option for you, because naturally a DB will be slower to access. It makes more sense to implement a DB if you have multiple clients that need to access the data, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.